# JSON schema validation while executing POST request and reading POST data entered by user using spring boot rest api

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, post, json-schema-validator

How to validate (using a specified schema) a **JSON input** by the user during a **POST request using a specified schema** (we have to validate the JSON data each time it is received through the POST request)? Also, how to actually extract data entered by the user from a post request? I did the following to **extract data entered by the user**:

```
@PostMapping("/all-configs")
public Animal createConfig( @RequestBody Animal ani) {
try {
    System.out.println(ani);//output: net.company.sprinboot.model.Animal@110e19d9
    System.out.println(ani.toString());//output: net.company.sprinboot.model.Animal@110e19d9
    String str = ani.toString();
    System.out.println(str);//output: net.company.sprinboot.model.Animal@110e19d9
}
```

How can I actually read the JSON data entered by the user in the post request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to validate a JSON input by user during a POST request using a
> specified schema (we have to validate the JSON data each time it is
> received through the POST request)?

Add the annotation `@Valid`(from `javax.validation.valid`), like so:

```
public Animal createConfig(@Valid @RequestBody Animal ani) {
```

On your Animal **DTO**, add annotations on the field(s) that you want to be validated, example:

```
public class Animal implements Serializable {
    ...

    @Size(max = 10)
    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    ... 
}
```

When Spring Boot finds an argument annotated with @Valid, it bootstraps Hibernate Validator(JSR 380 implementation) and ask it to perform bean validation.

When the validation fails, Spring Boot throws a `MethodArgumentNotValidException`.

> Also, how to actually extract data entered by the user form a post
> request?

Use the getter method on your Animal POJO. Example:

```
String name = ani.getName();
```

**UPDATE:**

> Also, if I have a json like: {"hype": {"key1":"value1"} }… then how
> can I access value1 in hype.key1?

```
@RestController
public class Main {
    @PostMapping("/all-configs")
    public void createConfig(@Valid @RequestBody Animal ani) {
        Map<String, String> hype = ani.getHype();
        System.out.println(hype.get("key1"));
    }
}

public class Animal implements Serializable {
    private Map<String, String> hype;

    public Map<String, String> getHype() {
        return hype;
    }

    public void setHype(Map<String, String> hype) {
        this.hype = hype;
    }
}
```

Output:

> value1

Comment: Thanks for your response @jumping_monkey. Also, if I have a json like: {"hype": {"key1":"value1"} }… then how can I access value1 in hype.key1?

Comment: Hi @jumping_monkey , any suggestions for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62921359/not-able-to-integrate-liquibase-with-my-spring-boot-project-getting-error-with ?